# It is about finding the coefficients of $x^n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$p(x) = \left(\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}\right)^3$$
I am to find the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in this. I am dumfounded, can anyone help me? I know that it uses combinatorics but can't exactly find the equation.

Comment: This is the number of nonnegative integers $n,m,k<10$ such that $n+m+k=21$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You obtain the desired coefficient by the long division

$$\frac{x^{30}-3x^{20}+3x^{10}-1}{(x-1)^3}.$$ Only the term $x^{30}$ plays a role and you can perform three successive divisions by $x-1$. Each time, the coefficients are the prefix sum of the coefficients of the dividend.

$$\frac{x^{30}}{x-1}=x^{29}+x^{28}+x^{27}+x^{26}+\cdots$$

$$\frac{x^{30}}{(x-1)^2}=x^{28}+2x^{27}+3x^{26}+4x^{25}+\cdots$$

$$\frac{x^{30}}{(x-1)^3}=x^{27}+3x^{26}+6x^{25}+10x^{24}+\cdots$$

The coefficients are triangular numbers, and that of $x^{21}$ is $T_7$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$$p(x)=(1+x+...+x^9)^3 = (1+x+...+x^9) \times (1+x+...+x^9) \times (1+x+...+x^9)$$

Answer (score 0):

$p(x)= (1-x^{10})^3 (1-x)^{-3}$.

Now use the general binomial formula $$(1-x)^{-3}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{3+k-1}{k}x^k$$

(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) e.g.) for the second

The first part is just the standard binomial $(1-\binom{3}{1}x^{10} + \binom{3}{2}x^{20} - x^{30})$.

So to get the coefficient of $x^{21}$ in the product, we get $$1 \cdot \binom{23}{21} + (-3)\cdot \binom{13}{11} + 3\binom{3}{1}$$ in total.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite followed, could you break it down further. Sorry!

Comment: @VikingMarauder You know or believe the general binomial?

Comment: yes. I do get the general binomial expression.

Comment: @VikingMarauder then what’s the remaining issue?

Comment: But i don't get the multiplication of the binomial expressions to give the last equation you got

Comment: Aah now I get it, after close retrospection. Thank you a ton!

Comment: @VikingMarauder you're welcome. You need a power from each term that so that the sum of their exponents is $21$ and look at those coefficients.

Comment: Yes thank you a lot I figured it now